# Python : sort a GTK treeview

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

I don't understand how the `gtk.Treeview()` list model works:

From what I understand I have to wrap the lismodel in a `gtk.TreeModelSort()` but when I do that, I can't access the listmodel methods anymore..

```
    lm = gtk.ListStore(object)
    listmodel = gtk.TreeModelSort(lm)
    for f in files:
        listmodel.append([f])
    return listmodel
```

**AttributeError: 'gtk.TreeModelSort' object has no attribute 'append'**

I'm working with [this example](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/sec-CellRenderers.html#filelistingfig) ([source](http://pygtk.org/pygtk2tutorial/examples/filelisting.py)): how would one make the table sortable on every column?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `gtk.TreeModelSort` is just a model (interface for access), it does not actually store anything. In fact, you don't need to invoke it yourself to make your table sortable. The simplest way is to let GTK do the sorting for you, which means that you have to store C data and not Python objects in your table. So, change your `make_list()` method to

```
listmodel = gtk.ListStore(str)
```

instead of `object`. Then you just have to tell the `gtk.TreeView` that clicking on the first column header should sort according to the first column in the `gtk.ListStore` by putting

```
self.tvcolumn[0].set_sort_column_id(0)
```

into your constructor. To sort by file size you'd add an extra colum consisting of `int` in the list store and use that as sort column id etc.

**Edit**: Ok let me spell the last thing out:

```
listmodel = gtk.ListStore(str, int)
for f in files:
    file_size = os.stat(os.path.join(self.dirname, f)).st_size
    listmodel.append([f, file_size])
```

puts the file size in the second column of the store. Then, to sort by file size you can just add

```
self.tvcolumn[1].set_sort_column_id(1)
```

In general, I would recommend to restructure your code that everything is stored in the `ListStore` once at the beginning. That way, you can code the cell rendering much easier by just tying each view column to a store column.

Comment: Thank you very much, it works great ; but only for the first col. The others raise a `GtkWarning: gtk_list_store_set_sort_column_id: assertion 'header != NULL' failed` I guess I'm not [quite there yet](http://www.daa.com.au/pipermail/pygtk/2011-February/019426.html) :)

Comment: Could you guys post a full version? It's hard to adjust it to make it work.